# Focus on a TextBox based on its input check

Tags: vb.net, textbox, messagebox, buttonclick

I want my program to check whether the inputs in a `TextBox` meet certain condition. If the target condition is not met, the cursor should focus back on that particular `TextBox`.

My code:

```
Private Sub ButtonSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSubmit.Click
    EnterVotes.LabelCan1.Text = CandName1.Text
    EnterVotes.Labelcan2.Text = CandName2.Text
    EnterVotes.LabelCan3.Text = CandName3.Text
    EnterVotes.LabelCan4.Text = CandName4.Text
    EnterVotes.LabelCan5.Text = CandName5.Text

    If CandName1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in Candidate 1")

    End If

    loading.Show()
    Me.Hide()
```

Comment: Note that `CandName1.Text = ""` is quite unreliable. Something like `CandName1.Text.Trim().Length <1` would be more trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

> If CandName1.Text = ""  Then
>  //Show your message here
>  // CandName1.focus()//to return to that textbox 
>  Else
>  //Show your
>   message here End If

use the method focus() to return and re-write into that textbox

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple

just check if the value of the text is > 1
then put focus on the textbox

heres an example

```
if txtbox.text.value < 1 then
messagebox.show("You must enter data for textbox")
txtbox.focus()
end if
```

and then continue method for each text box you are working with

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried it but the next part of the program is kicking in. Because I have a show() the next form when the submit is pressed it is telling me that i have nothing in the text box but also then loading the next form. Is there an IF i can put on the show the next form so that it checks all text boxes before showing the next form? PLEASE

Comment: I have done this, but now the message box wont go!! Im getting closer to the solution. Thanks for your help.  While CandName1.Text = ""
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in Candidate 1")
            CandName1.Focus()



        End While
        loading.Show()
        Me.Hide()

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it sounds like there might be some basics you need to touch on.

Answer (score 0):

Could get fancy and use some linq to go threw your names.

```
Dim Candidate() As TextBox
Candidate = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(c) c.Name.Contains("CandName")).ToArray()

Dim i As Integer = 0

While i < Candidate.Count
    If(Candidate(i).text.value < 1)
       MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in Candidate " & (i + 1).ToString())
       Candidate(i).Focus()
       Exit While
    End If  
    i += 1
    End While
```

This way you can check all your candidates in one shot.  This is untested code, but I think it should work.

You can play around with this and edit however you please it's pretty flexible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the way but not very efficient.

```
    If CandName1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in Candidate 1")
        CandName1.Focus()
    Else
        CandName2.Focus()
    End If



    If CandName2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an name in Candidate 2")
        CandName3.Focus()
    Else
        CandName3.Focus()
    End If

    If CandName3.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in Candidate 3")
        CandName3.Focus()

    Else
        CandName4.Focus()
    End If

    If CandName4.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in candidate 4")
        CandName4.Focus()
    Else
        CandName5.Focus()
    End If

    If CandName5.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pleae enter a name in candidat 5")
        CandName5.Focus()
    Else
        loading.Show()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If String.IsNullOrWhitespace( CandName1.Text ) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in Candidate 1")
    CandName1.Focus()
    Return
End If
```

... for all five

```
loading.Show()
Me.Hide()
```

You want to make sure to exit this early with the Return statements so you don't get to the code:

```
loading.Show()
Me.Hide()
```